# Select2 ajax is correctly calling webservice, but then doing nothing after

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm setting up a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) with the following JavaScript

```
$j("#" + name).select2({ 
  placeholder: "",
  width:"300px",
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: { 
    url: "/MyService.asmx/ServiceMethod",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (term) {
      return {
      q: term // search term
      };
    },
    results: function (data) {
      alert('results');
      return {results: data};
    },
    success: function() {
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
      alert('error');
    },
  },
});
```

The method I'm calling is the following:

```
<WebMethod(enableSession:=True)>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Function ServiceMethod(q as String) As String
    Dim temp As String = "[{'id':'35','text':'Drew'}]"
    Return temp
End Function
```

I also have `<ScriptService()>` around the class.  The enableSession is there because eventually I'm going to be running a lot of logic in the service that requires it, but for now I'm just trying to return a simple string with JSON.

I've put a breakpoint in the webservice, and I know it is being called.  I know it is returning the JSON.  I also know that the select2 expects "id" and "text" in the JSON return

My problem is the following:  after I input 3 characters, the data function calls (I put an alert in it), the webservice breakpoint is hit, but none of the results, success, or error events fire afterwards.  The select2 just spins and nothing ever happens.  No javascript errors are entered in the console, and I'm at a loss about even where to look for information as to why the ajax isn't handling the returned value from the service.

Can anyone point me in the direction of at least where to look to see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I fixed this myself after getting a hint to look at the network log.  The service was returning correctly, but it was returning XML, not JSON.  I had to make 2 modifications and everything worked.

My working ajax:

```
ajax: { 
  url: "/MyService.asmx/ServiceMethod",
  type: 'POST',
  params: {
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  data: function (term, page) {
    return JSON.stringify({ q: term, page_limit: 10 });
  },
  results: function (data) {
    return {results: data};
  },
},
```

The important changes were the type, putting the contentType in the params wrapper, and JSON.stringify-ing the data.  I'm going to change what's passed and how its passed, but things are at least communicating now.  Hope this helps anyone else who was looking for a similar solution.